# What is better solution for validate form TextBoxs value?

Tags: c#, wpf, logic

In my system has many forms for insert and edit database registers

But before to save date in database, I need validate any camp, validate it values is empty or not, validate TextBox.Text lenght, etc...

I validated they with many many if's

```
if (tbName.Text.Equals("")) { }
if (tbPass.Password.Equals("")) { }
if (tbEmail.Text.Equals("")) { }
if (tbTelephone.Text.Equals("")) { }

if (tbNome.Text.Length < 4) { }
if (tbPass.Password.Length < 5) { }
if (!tbEmail.Text.Contains('@')) { }
```

but it is very no efficiency and I don't know any other solution for this

What solution is usual for this?

Comment: [First google hit on WPF Validation](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/). You should be using MVVM and not manipulating or getting UI elements' properties directly.

Comment: @HighCore hummm I'm beginner in WPF, can you tell me more about this or give me a reference for study, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is by hand so it will have some syntax errors
You will probably also want to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged
Then Validation

```
public Class ValidatedText 
{
    private string vText;
    private bool valid = true;
    Int23 maxLen = 0;
    public bool Valid 
    {   
       get { return valid; }
       set 
       {  
          if (valid == value) return;
          valid = value;
       }
    } 
    public string Vtext 
    {  
       get { return vText; }
       set 
       {  
          if (vText == value) return;
          if (value.Len < 0) 
          {
              Valid = false;
              return;
          }
          // do additional validation here
          vText = value;
       } 
   }
   public ValidatedText (string VText; Int32 MaxLen)
   {   vText = Vtext; maxLen - MaxLen;   }
}
```